# I have to disable the MSI and enable the usual qty field only in the magento 2.3.5 version

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, qty, msi, multi-source-inventory

I have to disable the MSI and enable the usual qty field only in the Magento 2.3.5 version

https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/disable-sources-in-multi-source-inventory-magento-2/

I tried to use the modules listed on this blog, via the composer. It removes the modules but I am still not getting the usual qty and advance inventory fields in the product form.

I also tried some limited modules which were installed during the magento installation, and not required.
but it still didn't worked.
the list of those modules is below, in the post.
so I just wanted to know, what is that which I am missing here, and if there is any solution which someone has tried ??

```
Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl

Magento_InventoryAdminUi

Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout

Magento_InventoryBundleProduct

Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi

Magento_InventoryCache

Magento_InventoryCatalog

Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi

Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch

Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct

Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi

Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer

Magento_InventoryConfiguration

Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection

Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi

Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi

Magento_InventoryElasticsearch

Magento_InventoryExportStock

Magento_InventoryExportStockApi

Magento_InventoryGraphQl

Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct

Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi

Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer

Magento_InventoryImportExport

Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification

Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi

Magento_InventoryProductAlert

Magento_InventoryRequisitionList

Magento_InventoryReservationCli

Magento_InventoryReservations

Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi


Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi

Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator

Magento_InventoryShipping

Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi

Magento_InventorySourceSelection
```

Answer (score 3):

2.3 introduced a view table

Run this on your db

```
CREATE
OR REPLACE
VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS select
    distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
    `product`.`sku` AS `sku`
from
    ( `cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on
        (( `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id` )));
```

Also try using this to remove MSI

https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-inventory

There is a 2.3.5 version tagges so you should be okay

Comment: Yireo is best for this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run the below command and check if it works!

```
php bin/magento module:disable -f Magento_Inventory Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStockApi Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventoryExportStock Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection Magento_InventoryRequisitionList Magento_InventoryGraphQl
```

```
php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento c:f

php bin/magento i:rei

php bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

I hope this helps!